# Making a spring boot fat jar file with gradle WITHOUT a spring boot gradle plug-in (no access to bootJar)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, fatjar

I have a spring-boot application in which I loaded all the necessary (or so I believe) dependencies to run without using spring-boot initializer or the spring-boot gradle plug-in. These tools are not available for me at my work. I can run the application through intellij without issues, but when attempting to run a fat jar, I am met with

`No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.`

Now the spring.factory files ARE located inside the fat jar (there are multiples of them) and they are inside the meta-inf directory.

Spring boot has so much automated functionality, I am not sure where to begin. There are a lot of similar posts and everyone just tells people to use the spring-boot gradle plugin bootJar task but as I said these are not available to me. I need to get it running without those tools,
if anyone has insight into what the issue may be or how to resolve it, any help is appreciated. I will try to add more details later.

I am using spring-boot v. 2.1.1 and spring 5.1.4

Comment: Don't... This will only lead you down a rabbithole. Just fix the availablility of the Spring Boot plugin and use that.

Comment: that is sadly not possible as these tools are not available at my workllace, nor will they be anytime soon.

Comment: I have used IntelliJ to make the fat jar versusu my gradle task, and it is working just fine. Would be great to have a working gradle task but this is an acceptable workaround.

Comment: So basically you have the IKEA instructions for a PAX closet and an empty toolbox but aren’t allowed to go to IKEA to get the materials (the jars) or the tools (the plugins). What prevents you from simply adding `plugin ‘spring-boot’` to your Gradle build? Also I wouldn’t call this an acceptable workaround, it might work out of shear luck instead of having a proper Spring Boot jar. You can download the dependencies (hopefully the right ones and right dependencies!) so what prevents you from manually downloading the Spring Boot plugin, put it in your project and import it in your build?